# How to Scrape Json Text Format using Python

Tags: python, json, selenium, beautifulsoup, webdriver

As i wanted to scrape the data from this website but it gives me an error with no result

```
 import requests
    import time

headers={
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

url='https://api.github.com/repositories?since=0'
res = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
data =res.json()
print(data["id"])

print(data["node_id"])
```

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: The request works correctly. The data you get back is a list of repositories, so address it a as a list:

print(data[0]["id"])

Comment: what if i used loop for to get all then how??

Answer (score 2):

Json data is in an array. So to grab id value you have to iterate over the array.

```
import requests
   
headers={
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}
url='https://api.github.com/repositories?since=0'
res = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
data =res.json()

for id in data:
    print(id['id'])
```

**Output:**

```
1
26
27
28
29
31
35
36
42
43
48
52
53
54
56
61
63
65
68
71
73
74
75
92
93
95
98
102
105
118
119
120
127
129
130
131
137
139
140
141
142
144
165
177
179
185
186
190
191
192
193
195
199
203
204
205
206
207
208
211
212
213
217
218
220
230
232
237
245
248
249
251
252
256
257
267
273
279
293
305
307
312
314
319
320
322
324
329
332
334
339
351
360
362
363
364
365
367
368
369
```

Comment: Is there any way to extract one million rows in this i got only 369 but i want  1 million rows

Comment: To extract 1 million or 10 millions is a pretty simple matter but your question has  lack of enough information to do that